# useContext is throwing object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator) error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to experiment creating a generic reusable Provider component, users can decided to pass in their context, or use a default context.

The issue im facing, is the following:

> Error: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

**Provider itself**

```
import React, { useReducer, createContext } from 'react';

export const defaultContext = (context) => {
  let BaseContext = context;
  if (!context) {
    console.log('is this gettinged caled');
    BaseContext = createContext({});
  }
  console.log('BaseContext', BaseContext);
  return {
    BaseContext,
  };
};

function useGenericProvider(reducer, initState, context?) {
  const { BaseContext } = defaultContext(context ? context : null);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initState);

  const OurProvider = React.useMemo(() => {
    const myProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
      return (
        <BaseContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
          {children}
        </BaseContext.Provider>
      );
    };
    return myProvider;
  }, []);

  return {
    OurProvider,
  };
}
export { useGenericProvider };
```

How the context is being used..

**Child.tsx**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { defaultContext } from './useGenericReducer';

const Child = () => {
  const { BaseContext } = defaultContext(null);
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(BaseContext);
  console.log('state *******', BaseContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{state}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

**Parent.tsx**

```
import React, { useReducer, useState } from 'react';
import { useGenericProvider } from './useGenericReducer';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import MainApp from './MainApp';
import './style.css';
import Child from './Child';

interface IinitState {
  count: number;
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const initState: IinitState = {
    count: 0,
  };
  function reducer(state: IinitState, action: any) {
    switch (action) {
      case 'ADD':
        return {
          ...state,
          count: state.count + 1,
        };
      case 'SUB':
        return {
          ...state,
          count: state.count - 1,
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }

  const { OurProvider } = useGenericProvider(reducer, initState);
  return (
    <OurProvider>
      <Child />
    </OurProvider>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Reproducible example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/xxtt-react-usereducer-geph38?file=index.tsx

Comment: You're providing an object: `value={{ state, dispatch }}` but you're consuming it as though it's an array: `const [state, dispatch] = useContext(BaseContext);` Which one do you want?

Comment: ooopsss... i meant to destructure state and dispatch as an object... let me see if that changes the outcome.

Comment: destructure {state, dispatch} solved the above issue, but im getting state as undefined now, and im not sure why... Ideally want to state to be available on the child component.